# Embedding links in shiny tables

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a table in shiny so that each element of the table is a hyperlink to a new page but in such a way that the new page (to be created by shiny) knows which cell was clicked on. So, for example, I click on cell (i,j) and that takes me to a new page with a plot based upon the i and j values that I selected. I can do this using php and/or cookies, but I'm looking for a solution within shiny if possible.

Any ideas?

Note: An alternative is for me to use php and the HTML UI, but then I need the ability for R to return an array and for me to be able to refer to elements of that array within the html. Is that any easier?

Comment: I asked this question on Shiny google group forum. But no answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, but Shiny does not support something like that, so I created my table with java-script in HTML code

Comment: @Paul I'm looking for something similar. Is it possible to create a column containing links in a shiny dataTableOutput?

Comment: @Thomas I think yes, but I stopped using shiny dataTableOutput in my project and I started creating the table using JavaScript, because it gives more possibilities. I would advice you to do the same

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your questions, I ask you to update your shiny to the last version to avoid undesirable errors.

Generally you need two JavaScript functions (which is already implemented in shiny but it is not well documented) to communicate with server:

**Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler** and **Shiny.onInputChange in javascript**

here is my code:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Load the ggplot2 package which provides
# the 'mpg' dataset.
library(ggplot2)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),

    # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
    fluidRow(
      column(4, 
             selectInput("man", 
                         "Manufacturer:", 
                         c("All", 
                           unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
      ),
      column(4, 
             selectInput("trans", 
                         "Transmission:", 
                         c("All", 
                           unique(as.character(mpg$trans))))
      ),
      column(4, 
             selectInput("cyl", 
                         "Cylinders:", 
                         c("All", 
                           unique(as.character(mpg$cyl))))
      )        
    ),
    # Create a new row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
    ),
    tags$head(tags$script("var f_fnRowCallback = function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex,     iDisplayIndexFull ){
      $('td', nRow).click( function(){Shiny.onInputChange('request_ij',     [$(this).parent().index(),$(this).index()])} );
}                                        

Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('showRequested_ij', function(x) { 

    alert(x)
})"))
  )  
)
```

I just used "alert(x)" to show returned values from server. You can take care of a good JavaScript function to represent your data better. if you are looking to open new windows you may use:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write(x);
```

**Server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data <- mpg
    if (input$man != "All"){
      data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
    }
    if (input$cyl != "All"){
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$trans != "All"){
      data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
    }
    data
  },options =  list(
  fnRowCallback = I("function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull )     {f_fnRowCallback( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) }")))
  observe({   
    if(!is.null(input$request_ij)){
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "showRequested_ij", paste( "row:     ",input$request_ij[1],"    col: ",input$request_ij[2]))}
    })
})
```