# Shiny and JavaScript interaction with session$sendCustomMessage

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

If I use the `session$sendCustomMessage` command in my server file and input a list of three things, how do I access the three different things in my `message-handler.js` file?

Say my call looks like this:

```
session$sendCustomMessage(type='testmessage', message=list(pid=pid, cid=cid, query=sql))
```

In my .js file I want to use pid, cid and query seperately, any ideas on how I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701030/embedding-links-in-shiny-tables/25676345#25676345
It might answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would access them as `message.pid, message.cid` etc. The list is passed as `JSON`. An example adapted from http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("sendCustomMessage example"),
    fluidRow(
      column(4, wellPanel(
        sliderInput("controller", "Controller:",
                    min = 1, max = 20, value = 15),
        singleton(
          tags$head(tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("testmessage",
  function(message) {
    alert("The b variable is " + message.b);
  }
);'))
        )
      ))
    )
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session){
    observe({
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                                message = list(a = 1, b = 'text',
                                               controller = input$controller))
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: how would you do it vice versa? from client to server?